# How i can set the "Due Date" field (on the fly) to be equal to Today date, when the "Status" dropdown list is changed to "In progress"

Tags: development, javascript, jquery, list-form, jslink

I am working on an issue tracking list inside SharePoint enterprise server 2013, where it contains these fields:-

- 1. “Due Date”
- 2. Item status

Now our customer, asked us to implement this capability:-

When a user change the item status to be “In progress”, to change the “Due Date” to be equal to today date.

Now my question is what are the approaches I can follow within SharePoint, to implement this inside the create form, edit form & quick edit grid?

From a pure development point of view, I can write a JavaScript which fires when the item status got changed to “In progress”, and populate the “Due Date” field to be equal to today date.. But not sure how I can implement this inside SharePoint? In a way that can work on create & edit forms, and on the quick edit grid?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you would not do this using a workflow?

Comment: @AlexChance Setting a workflow will not work on the fly,,, i mean if i user create/edit an item and he change the item status ,, then the Due Date will not get the new value unless he saves the item.. and i want the user to be able to change the Due Date if he want.. i mean the idea is to set the Due Date to be equal to today date,if the user change the item status to be "In progress", but users can chnage the due Date if they want.. so workflow will not work in my case

Comment: I did not realize that was a requirement from the question. If you need that functionality prior to saving, then I believe your only options will be template overriding via JSLink. Event receiver will not work either since you need the change before item is saved.

Answer (score 3):

For client-side implementation, use JSLink to override field rendering. You can also add your javascript dropdown change handler to PostRender function of JSLink.

Using server side, you can use event receiver to calculate Due Date on item created and updated events.

Comment: ,, no need for server-side check at this stage,, but not sure how i can benefit from JSLink in my case? can you please adivce more ? does JSLINK allow me to update the field value on the fly based on another selection ?

Comment: There are plenty of samples out there. A simple postRender handler is shown here: https://kogzee.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/sharepoint-2013-using-client-side-rendering-jslink-to-change-column-widths-in-lists/

For quick edit, see http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/

Comment: This won't work in quick edit grid

Comment: @Aveenav thanks for the links, but before i go through them will JSLINK be able to work on quick edit  as seems Erin L mentioned it will not work ?

Comment: @ErinL can you adivce why JSLINK will not work on quick edit grid ? now i have some fields where i defined JSLINKs for them , mainly to disable them inside the quick edit grid (OnPreRender) and JSLINK seems to work inside quick edit grid.. now i did not use the PostRender but i assume it will work ... can you advice?

Comment: If it worked for you for that, then you should just try it for what you need now.

Comment: @johnG CSR is supported in Quick Edit like you say, and is the correct method to use here, since you want the user to have the option to change the date before they save

Answer (score 1):

Client side rendering or code to set fields won't work in datagrid view. I recommend using a workflow. Using the `Wait For` action (run workflow on create) is a better option than checking the status every time an item is edited.

[image]

Comment: setting a workflow will not work on the fly,,, i mean if i user create/edit an item and he change the item status ,, then the Due Date will not get the new value unless he saves the item.. and i want the user to be able to change the Due Date if he want.. i mean the idea is to set the Due Date to be equal to today date,if the user change the item status to be "In progress", but users can chnage the due Date if they want.. so workflow will not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

A simple workflow could accomplish this. [image]

May need to add some additional logic to prevent due date from being set again if the item is going to be modified frequently.

Comment: You can keep multiple updates from being an issue by using a `wait for` action. See my response.

Comment: @AlexChance Setting a workflow will not work on the fly,,, i mean if i user create/edit an item and he change the item status ,, then the Due Date will not get the new value unless he saves the item.. and i want the user to be able to change the Due Date if he want.. i mean the idea is to set the Due Date to be equal to today date,if the user change the item status to be "In progress", but users can chnage the due Date if they want.. so workflow will not work in my case